# I am trying to make videos of 59 mins and 59 secs, but the video created is always of smaller duration

Tags: opencv

I want to create videos for multiple cameras stored in MySQL database. At intervals of every 1 hour the duration of video should be 59 mins and 59 secs. The videos should be then uploaded to azure blob storage.

However, every time a video is created, it is of a smaller duration (for example, 44 or 45 mins). I am not getting any errors. What am I doing wrong? any suggestion will be of great help. Thank You.

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
import cv2
import pymysql
import time
import datetime
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess

def accessCamera(user_id, location_id, user_name, cursor):
    fix_path = '/home/****/****/'
    container_name = user_name

    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='******', account_key='*****+*****+****+/******')

    try:
        block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
    except:
        pass

    block_blob_service.set_container_acl(container_name, public_access=PublicAccess.Container)

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM xxxxx where user_id = ' + str(user_id) + ' and location_id = ' + str(location_id) + '')
    cameras = cursor.fetchall()
    camera = {}
    counter = 0
    out = {}
    hour = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H'))

    for x in cameras:
        try:
            os.makedirs(fix_path + x['ip_address'] + '_' + str(x['rtsp_port']) + '/videos/')
        except:
            pass
        rtsp_stream_link = 'rtsp://' + x['username'] + ':' + x['password'] + '@' + x['ip_address'] + ':' 
     + str(x['rtsp_port']) + '/stream=1'
        out[counter] = cv2.VideoWriter(fix_path + x['ip_address'] + '_' + str(x['rtsp_port']) + 
    '/videos/' + str(hour) + '.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 1, (1920,1080))
        camera[counter] = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_stream_link)
        counter = counter + 1

    print("    #==================================================")
    print("    #-- Loaded Cameras Now Saving Video for Location " + str(location_id) + " - " + 
     str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')))
    print("    #==================================================")
    framecount = 0    
    while True:

        counter = 0
        for x in cameras:
            check,frame=camera[counter].read()

            if check == True:
                out[counter].write(frame)
            else:
                continue

            minutes = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%M'))
            if int(minutes) == 59 and framecount >= 3599:
                out[counter].release()
                block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, fixpath + x['ip_address'] + '_' 
     + str(x['rtsp_port']) + '/videos/' + hour + '.avi', x['ip_address'] + '_' + x['rtsp_port'] + 
     '/videos/' + hour + '.avi')
                print("#==================================================")
                print("#-- Video Saved - " + 
     str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')))
                print("#==================================================")
                threading.Thread._stop(self)
                exit(1)
            counter = counter + 1
        framecount = framecount + 1

#===========================================================================
# -- Main function
#===========================================================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Time - " + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')))
    flag  = 1
    while True:
        if (str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%S')) == '54' and 
     str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%M')) == '59') or flag == 1:
            print("#======================================================")
            print("#-- Get All Users and Locations to create Threads - " + 
     str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')))
            print("#======================================================")

            db = pymysql.connect('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'password', 'xxxxxx')
            cursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor1 = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute('select locations.id,locations.user_id,users.username from locations inner 
     join users on users.id = locations.user_id')
            user = cursor.fetchall()

            for x in user:
                thread = threading.Thread(target=accessCamera,args= 
     (int(x['user_id']),int(x['id']),x['username'],cursor1,))
                print("    #==================================================")
                print('    #-- Thread created for location ' + str(x['id']) + ' - ' + 
     str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')))
                print("    #==================================================")
                thread.daemon = True
                thread.start()

            time.sleep(1)
            flag = 0
            # print("    #==================================================")
            # print("    #-- Sleeping Current Thread for 1 minutes - " + 
    str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')))
            # print("    #==================================================")
```